# Playframework evolutions + SQL Server. Generate correct schema script?

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, slick, playframework-2.3, playframework-evolutions

I've been trying with no success to run evolutions + slick to generate schema for a MSQLServer database.

I am using Play 2.3.x, scala 2.11.6, slick, and SQLServer 2014.

I could make it connect as well, but the script which is generated contains lots of "errors" relates to data types, like the use of BOOLEAN and TIMESTAMP which are types that SQLServer does not use.

The script should use the types BIT instead of BOOLEAN, DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP, and UNIQUEIDENTIFIER instead of UUID.

Does anyone know a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

These datatypes and all specific to database so there is no workaround here.
You have change the data types based on the selected database otherwise you will get the same error in another database as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Isn't there a way of mapping data types?